# How to change slider hover color in MAUI?

Tags: maui

I'm developping a glorified audio player which features a slider which is central to the UI.

I'm having a hard time though because I can't change the slider hover color (blue, I presume. I am colorblind). That color appears when hovering on the elapsed part of the slider.

[image: MAUI slider hover color]

I tried overriding the slider properties for all states in a global stylesheet, to no avail.

```
<Style TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I also tried overriding Slider properties for WinUI in Platform\Windows\app.xaml:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="MPC.MForms.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    xmlns:local="using:MPC.MForms.WinUI">
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

Does someone know if changing that color is possible? Otherwise, would someone happen to know a third-party MAUI control library featuring sliders that I could use?

Update: Here's what I came up with according to Liyun Zhang - MSFT's answer.
Simply add this in your Platforms\Windows\App.xaml file:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver">Red</Color>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

It's about simply overriding the SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver resource which is used for slider hover colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color has been set in the Slider's default style on the windows platform. There is a `<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">` in the style and set the color. So you need to set the color by your self.

You can try to copy the default style to the Maui project's Platform\Windows\app.xaml and set the color by the setting the following property in the `<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">`.

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" /> //you can change the Red to the color you want
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Or you can copy the following code directly.

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFill}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFill}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,0,-7,0" />
            <Setter Property="IsFocusEngagementEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyle">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackground}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                                <Border
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          CornerRadius="4" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFillDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFillPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFillPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusEngagementStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusDisengaged" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedHorizontal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusEngagedVertical">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SliderContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                FontWeight="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                Foreground="{ThemeResource SliderHeaderForeground}"
                Margin="{ThemeResource SliderTopHeaderMargin}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="SliderContainer"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Background="{ThemeResource SliderContainerBackground}"
                Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                                <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" MinHeight="{ThemeResource SliderHorizontalHeight}">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource SliderPreContentMargin}" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource SliderPostContentMargin}" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Grid.Row="1" />
                                    <TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                    Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="0,0,0,4"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                    <TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Fill="{ThemeResource SliderInlineTickBarFill}"
                    Height="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                    <TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                    Height="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="0,4,0,0"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                    <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
                    Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                    DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                    Height="24"
                    Width="8"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FocusVisualMargin="-14,-6,-14,-6"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" MinWidth="{ThemeResource SliderVerticalWidth}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{ThemeResource SliderPreContentMargin}" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{ThemeResource SliderPostContentMargin}" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect"
                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2" />
                                    <TickBar x:Name="LeftTickBar"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                    Width="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="0,0,4,0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                    <TickBar x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Fill="{ThemeResource SliderInlineTickBarFill}"
                    Width="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                    <TickBar x:Name="RightTickBar"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Fill="{ThemeResource SliderTickBarFill}"
                    Width="{ThemeResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="4,0,0,0"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                                    <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"
                    Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                    DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                    Width="24"
                    Height="8"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    FocusVisualMargin="-6,-14,-6,-14"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!!! I'm having a hard time overriding just what I want, but I think I'll get it. This will add much more credibility to my app.

Comment: All right. Happy coding!